# Is it possible to have an opacified background layer which doesn't opacify its children?

Tags: css, xhtml, opacity

Let say I've this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>Layers Opacity</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
        <style type="text/css">
            div#container
            {
                background-color: black;
                width: 200px;
                height: 400px;
                padding-top: 50px;
                            opacity: 0.5;
            }

            ul#menu
            {
                background-color: red;
                width: 150px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                            opacity: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu 1</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu 2</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu 3</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu 4</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu 5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to have my "#menu" in full color, red. 
I tried to remove the inheritance by setting opacity to 1, but it doesn't work.
Did i make something wrong ? Or Is it simply not possible by this way ?

I could probably do a layer, outside my menu, and position it in background with z-index, but I'm looking a way in pure css, without to modify my xhtml.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency):

> If the object is a container element,
>   then the effect is as if the contents
>   of the container element were blended
>   against the current background using a
>   mask where the value of each pixel of
>   the mask is .

Since your menu is contents of the container, it will also have the containers opacity applied. Your only option is to apply a workaround such that your menu is not technically contained within the div. [This article](http://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/) also describes such an approach.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Putting the menu outside the container would be the normal fix; if you can't change the markup another approach is to avoid opacity entirely and use a semi-transparent PNG as the container background instead (with suitable AlphaImageLoader fix for IE6 if necessary).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are only trying to change the background of the element, you can use an rgba colour (CSS 3) in supporting browsers. Most browsers which don't support it can handle a translucent PNG.

See (blatant self-promotion) [CSS 3: RGBA today](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/) for a fuller explanation and some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a transparent png as a background image for modern browsers and a filter in IE6, as described in this article: [Cross Browser Background Transparency With CSS](http://www.unintentionallyblank.co.uk/2007/05/07/cross-browser-background-transparency-with-css/)